# Need help understanding the proof regarding the locus of the feet of the perpendiculars from the focus of an ellipse to all of it's tangents

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

From page 12-13 of Arnold's "Real Algebraic Geometry"

---

I understand the following perfectly well. I included here because it is referenced in the next proof, which I need help with.

[image]

[image]

---

Now lets move onto the problem/proof that I need help understanding:

***Problem: Find the locus of the feet R of the perpendiculars drawn from the focus F2 of an ellipse to all of its tangents.***

(Skipping the proof for degenerate cases...._

[image]

[image]

---

Here is the part I wish to understand better:

"Therefore the locus of R is obtained by the locus of $F_2'$ as the result of a double contraction to the point $F_2$"

The next paragraph expands on what happens under this double contraction. I get quite lost trying to understand what is happening here. If somebody could explain to me what's going on, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: There is a circle with center $F_1$ and radius $2a$ and it gets transformed by a [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothety) with center $F_2$ and ratio $1/2$.  So, it becomes a circle with radius $a$ and center at the midpoint between $F_1$ and $F_2$

Comment: Probably by "double contraction" the author means "a homothety of ratio $1/2$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the midpoint $A$ of $F_1F_2'$: its locus is a circle $c$ of centre $F_1$ and radius $a$. If $R$ is the midpoint of $F_2F_2'$, then $AR$ is parallel to $F_1F_2$ and half its length. Hence the locus of $R$ is the translated of circle $c$ by a vector $\overrightarrow{F_1O}$, i.e. a circle of centre $O$ and radius $a$.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Thank you.